# Magento shopper theme mulitple cart-top-title on "add to cart"

Tags: magento

I'm using the Magento Shopper Theme (http://shopper.queldorei.com/).

When I add a product to my shops cart, it adds multiple elemtns of

```
<div class="cart-top-title">
<a href="https://droppinstudio.dk/horsepony/index.php/checkout/cart/" class="clearfix">
<span class="icon"></span>Cart</a></div>
```

I've figured out that it is the jQuery that makes the mistake here:

```
function setLocationAjax(url, id)
{
   ...
       if (data.status != 'ERROR' && $('.cart-top-container').length) {
          $('.cart-top-container').replaceWith(data.cart_top);
       }   
   ...
}
```

Does anybody have a good idea of what to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Erwin, [that helped me figure out what is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13844528/1369235).

The CartController is located in app/code/local/Excellence/Ajax/controllers/ and is actually named IndexController.php.

Line 52-54 sets the data.cart_top response:

```
$sidebar_header = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('cart_top')->toHtml();
Mage::register('referrer_url', $this->_getRefererUrl());
$response['cart_top'] = $sidebar_header;
```

A fix could be to change the way the *cart_top* block is designed, and remove the 'cart-top-title'  from cart_top.phtml and put it in a file of its own and include it in header.phtml.

Turns out the acutal replacement happens in line 85 of ajaxcart.js (function setLocationAjax).

A quick fix for me was to delete the div with jQuery like so:

```
if (data.status != 'ERROR' && $('.cart-top-container').length) {
  $('.cart-top-title').remove();
  $('.cart-top-container').replaceWith(data.cart_top);
}
```

js file here: skin/frontend/default/shopper/js/ajaxcart/ajaxcart.js

cart_top.phtml here: app/design/frontend/default/shopper/template/checkout/cart/cart-top.phtml

header.phtml here: app/design/frontend/default/shopper/template/page/html/header.phtml

Comment: Glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look into the CartController, and change the response variable (data.cart_top).

The location of CartController depends on the module the theme uses. The core CartController is located in app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php.

Hope this helps.